# how to get the next word from a string according to list element in python

Tags: python, string

I am new to python and trying to solve this problem.

`words = ['plus', 'Constantly', 'the']`

`string = "Plus, I Constantly adding new resources, guides, and the personality quizzes to help you travel beyond the Guidebook"`

`output: I adding Guidebook`

here I want to match the list element to the string and get the next word from the string to construct a new word.

I tried to do it by splitting the word into list and check if they are in the list. But the 'Plus,' won't match because of the ',' and also there has two 'the' but I only need to get the last word after 'the'

Comment: you could try to iterate through the string letter by letter and each time you get a match for the first letter in your next word check if that word is there. Alternatively you could use regex to get the index of the match for each word and then find the next word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use regex to split `string` by words (the pattern used is `[\w]+`).  Then you can build a dictionary of the pairs, so that you can look up the first word to retrieve the following word.

```
import re
words = ['plus', 'Constantly', 'the'] 
string = "Plus, I Constantly adding new resources, guides, and the personality quizzes to help you travel beyond the Guidebook"

string_splits = re.findall(r'[\w]+',string)
pairs = {x:y for x,y in zip(map(lambda x: x.lower(), string_splits), string_splits[1:])}
print(' '.join(pairs.get(word.lower()) for word in words))
```

Edit to expand the dict comprehsion;

```
pairs = {}
for x,y in zip(map(lambda x: x.lower(), string_splits), string_splits[1:]):
    pairs[x] = y
```

Comment: Great idea, I love the pairs dictionary for having the word and the next one together. Can you please format the pairs into multiple lines, the way it would be easier to read.

Comment: You can use `print('\n'.join(f'{word} {pairs.get(word.lower())}' for word in words))`

Comment: oops, you mean instead of the dict comprehension, let me edit and add